# Schwinger function with and without temperature

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, temperature

I have always been confused with the differences and relation between many-body theory with and without temperature. Suppose I have a theory described by some Hamiltonian $H = H_{0} + V$, where $H_{0}$ is the free part (typically, the kinetic energy) and $V$ some interaction (say, polynomial in the creation and annihilation fields).

**As far as I understand (please correct me if I am wrong)**, the difference between a many-body theory with temperature (statistical mechanics, condensed matter theory) and without temperature (field theory) is what one means by a Schwinger function. In other words, what average value one wants to study: in the case of a statistical mechanics system is at a mixed state $\rho_{\beta} = e^{-\beta H}$ and the expected value of an observable is given by:
$$\langle A\rangle_{\beta} := \frac{\operatorname{Tr}(e^{-\beta H}A)}{\operatorname{Tr}(e^{-\beta H})}$$
whilst in field theory, the system has an associated vacuum state $\Omega$ and one looks for the expected value of $A$ in the vacuum state:
$$\langle A\rangle := \langle \Omega, A\Omega\rangle.$$

Typically, $A$ is a polynomial in the creation and annihilation operators. These operators depend on both time and some coordinate (position, momentum) and one needs to introduce time ordering $\mathbb{T}$. In short, one studies either:
$$\langle \mathbb{T}(\prod_{i}a_{i}^{\#}(t))\rangle_{\beta}$$
or:
$$\langle \mathbb{T}(\prod_{i}a_{i}^{\#}(t))\rangle$$
In the above expressions, $\#$ denote either the creation $a^{\dagger}$ or annihilation operator $a$ and $i$ is some set of indices.

In the case of finite-temperature systems, the Schwinger function is supposed to be the thermal two point function:
$$S(x,t,x',t') = \langle \mathbb{T}a_{x}^{\dagger}(t)a_{x'}(t')\rangle$$
and in the absense of temperature, the same name is used to:
$$S(x,t,x',t') = \langle \mathbb{T}a_{x}^{\dagger}(t)a_{x'}(t')\rangle.$$

What I am really confused is: it seems that these are essentially the same theory (in the sense that they are described by the same Hamiltonian), but I can't relate them at all. I heard that the field theory is the zero temperature limit $\beta \to \infty$ of the finite-temperature system, but I have no idea if this is true or why this is true. More importantly, it is very confusing the fact that the term "Schwinger function" means different things depending on the context and I think the relation between these two theories should lie in the relation between the two Schwinger functions. I was not able to find these answers in the literature I know because these systems are usually treated separately. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You calculate things in the vacuum state because it is the _ground_ state, and at zero temperature, ground state is all that contributes to expectation values. If unsure of this, think about the behaviour of terms in the partition function as temperature is varied.